# 3D plots in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-3d

How could I plot the following data in 3 dimensions? (apparently, there are more than that!)

```
data = [[10, 10, 0.84496124031007758],
        [10, 20, 0.87209302325581395],
        [10, 30, 0.88139534883720927],
        [20, 10, 0.86201550387596892],
        [20, 20, 0.87441860465116272],
        [20, 30, 0.88992248062015500],
        [30, 10, 0.87984496124031009],
        [30, 20, 0.89922480620155043],
        [30, 30, 0.92015503875968996]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what kind of plot are you trying to get?  Try this for a scatter plot.  I'm also assuming your data is listed in `x,y,z` lists in your question.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x, y, z = zip(*data)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use DataMelt http://jwork.org/dmelt. You can parse this file in pythonic way as in the previous example ANF than use HPlot or HPlotJa or SPlot java classes to visualize the data. You can also export to Esp or pdf image files

Answer (score 0):

It's basicaly adding `projection='3d'` to your subplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure() # create new figure
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d') # add 3d plot

n = 100 # number of points

# random points
x = np.random.rand(n)
y = np.random.rand(n)
z = np.random.rand(n)

# make and show plot
ax.scatter(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

With `ax.scatter` you can configure points markers, color and others.

Looks like the figure
[image]